# Можно ли сделать свапы (для сенсорных экранов) на одном JS?

Tags: javascript

Или придется подключается какую то библиотеку.

Comment: Можно (V)( ;...; )(V)

Comment: по вашему библиотека не на одном js написана?

Comment: Так хотелось бы без использования

Answer (score 0):

[touch events](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Touch_events)
[deviceorientation](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Window/deviceorientation_event#%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D1%81_%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%83%D0%B7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%B8)
[devicemotion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/devicemotion_event#Browser_compatibility)
[gesture event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GestureEvent)
Как-то так. Мобильные фреймворки некоторые основные вещи поддерживают из коробки. React Native: [touches](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-touches), [gestures](https://reactnative.dev/docs/gesture-responder-system)